Switching db occasionally causes "Database not found: \'test\'"
Switching db occasionally causes "Database not found: \'test\'"
I deployed a distributed cnosdb environment, 3meta+3querytskv.
version： enterprise version cnosdb 2.4.2, revision d3e52d3177bf242e6a05064ba9b1166c9439e0d7
create database test;
\c test

When I repeatedly switched the db, I found that sometimes the switch was successful, and sometimes it failed: "Database not found: \'test\'"
test ❯ \c test
Cannot connect to database test.
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030017","error_message":"Database not found: \"test\""}

